# jquery load content immediately and then update every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just got this little script working, but there is some problem. I want that content updated every 10 seconds, but when site loaded it takes 10 seconds before content shows up, then updating works.

So how I can get that working so it loads content immediately and then start refreshing every 10 seconds. Thank you.

```
  hr = new Date().getHours();

  for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
     if (hr >= data[i][0] && hr <= data[i][1]) {
        $("#someContent").html(data[i][2]);

        break;
      }      
    }
```

Comment: Does the code you are showing sit inside a loop?

Comment: @penalse have you though of using Socket programming for updating your page content. What u are asking is polling. It is not recommended for high performance websites. Solutions like SignalR (.NET) or Node.JS Socket IO can be used for more professsional and optimized approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all create a function that updates the content:

```
function updateContent() {
    $("#someContent").html(data[i][2]); 
}
```

Then create an init function:

```
function init() {
    updateContent();
    setInterval(updateContent, 10000)
}
```

Call the init function once when ready:

```
init();
```

Explanation:

You need to seperate the "logic" from the "wiring". This means you split the code that **does** stuff from code that **calls** stuff. After you've done this. you can write additional wiring (calls) to the same logic, this keeps your code DRY.

Note:

The solution above is only safe if the updateContent() function is sync. This means: if it affecting the DOM directly. If it's going to load AJAX it is **unsafe** to use setInterval() as the server might need more time to answer than is provided by the interval.

If you deal with asynchronous code you want to reschedule after completion. A quick and dirty example:

```
function updateContent() {
    someFunctionReturningAPromise()
        .then(() => setTimeout(updateContent), 10000)
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
}

updateContent()
```

Comment: You should not call it _unsafe_. It's not an security issue, it's only bad practice because of reasons. Maybe tell more about this.

Comment: That's debatable, in the worst case it may cause a Denial Of Service which is considered a security risk.

Comment: @eisbehr Unsafe doesn't have to do with just security. It also describes code running outside managed context which can cause both, stability as well as security issues. More so stability in regards what the answer above describes.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the code inside the interval to happen immediately when the content loads.
A simple solution would be to extract it into a function and then call that function when the content loads and also call that function inside the setInterval callback.

```
// when content is loaded...
   doSomething(); 

// and again each 10 seconds...
   window.setInterval(function() {
        doSomething(); 
   }, 10000);

   function doSomething() {
      $("#someContent").html(data[i][2]);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some good explained answers here. I just want to give you another possibility. You could even use a self-executing named function to dot it with less overhead. Pretty simple and nice to maintain.

The advantage of using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` is, that it will wait for the execution of your code an then start the 10s timeout.

```js
(function runner() {
  $("#someContent").html(data[i][2]);
  setTimeout(runner, 10000);
})();
```

Comment: Your explanation on what the advantage of `setTimeout` is over `setInterval` sounds strange, both wait for 10 seconds and then execute the code. they are identical in that specific regard. The advantage of `setTimeout` is that is doesn't repeat itself after execution.

Comment: That was not what I mean. I mean that my approach wait for the execution of (_in this case_) `$("#someContent").html(data[i][2]);`. Let's say this line would take two seconds to execute, then `setInterval` would execute the next run 8 seconds after the execution, while `setTimeout` will execute the next run 10 seconds after this. @Nope

Comment: `setInterval` will not execute after 8 seconds if you have it set to execute after 10. It will execute after the number of seconds specified in the parameter.

Comment: Yes, I think you don't get the point of my answer. You can use `setInterval` if you want to execute the code exactly all 10 seconds. No matter if the code runs 2 or 5 seconds. But if you want to have a timeout between the executions of always 10 seconds, and not 8 or 5 seconds, then `setTimeout` in my approach is the better solution. It will be clearer if we would say the line would take 11 seconds for execution. Then the next interval start running before the last is already finished. That can't happen with `setTimeout`. @Nope